# Angular-cli 1.6 PWA Route redirect stops the server-worker from starting up

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

Am trying to use the @angular/service-worker 5.0.0 with Angular cli 1.6, the App works it caches when offline everything works, but when I change the main  \ route by redirecting to \home at startup the service-worker stops working and disappeared from chrom dev tool.
How can I setup the routing in the ngsw.config.json also where is the documantation for it. Here is my App-routning.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
    {path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomedModule'},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]},
  {path: 'errors', loadChildren: 'app/pages/errors/errors.module#ErrorsModule'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'errors', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Comment: I am facing similar problems. Did you find whats causing this issue or a work around?

Comment: No I gave up on @angular/service-worker and started using workbox its much better